# How to read python documentation?

Tags: python, module

I have a have a hard time understanding how does one come about knowing `datetime.datetime.now()` from the official module documentation. There is a mention of `datetime.datetime` but no where is the `.now()` mentioned. I just see it in Q/A forums as an answer to various problems.

Comment: [It's *right there*.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now)

Comment: Oh, thanks. Actually I've seen it before but since it said just "datetime.now()" i could  not make it work. So a class if followed by a classmethod ("class.classmethod.")?

Comment: It sounds like you got confused by the fact that the class and the module are both called `datetime`.

Comment: Yup. I fear I still am. Is the logic  "class.classmethod.object(atribute)" right? like in datetime.datetime.now()?

Comment: No, it's class.classmethod(arguments). The class part might be `datetime` or `datetime.datetime` depending on how you wrote your imports. The classmethod part is `now`. You're not passing any arguments, so it's `datetime.now()` or `datetime.datetime.now()` depending on whether you did `from datetime import datetime` or `import datetime`.

Comment: If you do `from datetime import datetime`, you've imported the datetime class, so you just write `datetime` to refer to the class. If you do `import datetime`, you've imported the datetime module, so you need to access the attribute named `datetime` on the module object to retrieve the class, by writing `datetime.datetime`.

Answer (score 2):

It **is** documented in the official documentation, right [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now). You were probably searching for `datetime.datetime.now()` while its actually under just `datetime.now()` because its a classmethod.